# Why is Evolution present and active but not visible as installed? How to get rid of it?

Tags: software-center, uninstall, evolution

When inspecting the running processes on Ubuntu 16.04, I noticed few processes of Evolution.

[image]

However, when I opened Ubuntu Software Center to uninstall Evolution, it's shown as not even having been installed.

[image]

Why is this? How can I get rid of Evolution? I don't want such processes which I never use, unnecessarily consume RAM.

Comment: Evolution MUA (mail user agent) software is not the evolution data-server you see in the process picture you added. The evolution data-server is part of gnome, the evolution mua is a mail program you can add to gnome (or other desktop).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the `evolution-data-server` package.

```
Description: evolution database backend server
 The data server, called "Evolution Data Server" is responsible for managing
 mail, calendar, addressbook, tasks and memo information.
```

e-d-s is part of the Gnome and Unity desktops. It runs the integrated calendar and address book.

For most users, removal is a Very Bad Idea: It's an essential set of backend services that those desktop environments require. Removing e-d-s will also remove those desktop environments!

Comment: So can I safely remove the evolution-data-server? I hope it'd have no effect on the time and calendar features that appear on the top right edge of the Ubuntu screen? Is removing it as simple as `sudo apt-get remove evolution-data-server`?

Comment: Can also be "safely" removed in later Ubuntu versions that are using Gnome Shell. There, it takes away your entire desktop *and* your login manager gdm. Safe it is, because you are left with an intact Ubuntu system. However, a restart leaves you to a terminal rather than bringing you on your desktop. That is fine, but only if you want that.